# small pokemon battle - enemy attacks three times in one turn

Tags: vb.net

(this is vb express on a console application btw) i'm a novice at programming, so bear with me -
i tried to make a small pokemon battle (cheesy, i know) and it worked okay except for the fact that the enemy attacked 3 times in one turn which was sort of a complication. here's my code - how can i fix this?

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim num As Integer
        Dim num1 As Integer
        Dim num2 As Integer
        Dim num3 As Integer

        num = 0
        Console.WriteLine("select the wild zigzagoon's health.")
        num3 = Console.ReadLine
        Console.WriteLine("select charmander's health.")
        num2 = Console.ReadLine
        Console.WriteLine("a wild zigzagoon appeared! go, charmander!")

        While num3 > 0 And num2 > 0
            Console.WriteLine("what will charmander do? use tackle(1), burn(2), smack(3) or ember(4)?")
            num1 = Console.ReadLine
            If num1 > 0 And num1 < 2 Then
                num3 = num3 - 15
                Console.WriteLine("charmander used tackle! zigzagoon took 15 damage! zigzagoon is on " & num3)
                num = num + 1
            ElseIf num = 1 Then
                num2 = num2 - 10
                Console.WriteLine("zigzagoon used tackle! charmander took 10 damage! charmander is now on " & num2)
            ElseIf num = 2 Then
                num2 = num2 - 20
                Console.WriteLine("zigzagoon used quick attack! charmander took 15 damage! charmander is now on" & num2)
            ElseIf num = 3 Then
                num2 = num2 - 25
                Console.WriteLine("zigzagoon used headbutt! charmander took 25 damage! charmander is now on" & num2)
            ElseIf num = 4 Then
                num2 = num2 - 40
                Console.WriteLine("zigzagoon used take down! charmander took 40 damage! charmander is now on " & num2)
            End If

            If num1 > 1 And num1 < 3 Then
                num3 = num3 - 20
                Console.WriteLine("charmander used burn! zigzagoon took 20 damage! zigzagoon is now on " & num3)
                num = num + 1
            ElseIf num = 1 Then
                num2 = num2 - 10
                Console.WriteLine("zigzagoon used tackle! charmander took 10 damage! charmander is now on " & num2)
            ElseIf num = 2 Then
                num2 = num2 - 20
                Console.WriteLine("zigzagoon used quick attack! charmander took 15 damage! charmander is now on" & num2)
            ElseIf num = 3 Then
                num2 = num2 - 25
                Console.WriteLine("zigzagoon used headbutt! charmander took 25 damage! charmander is now on" & num2)
            ElseIf num = 4 Then
                num2 = num2 - 40
                Console.WriteLine("zigzagoon used take down! charmander took 40 damage! charmander is now on " & num2)
                num = num - 4
            End If

            If num1 > 2 And num1 < 4 Then
                num3 = num3 - 30
                Console.WriteLine("charmander used smack! zigzagoon took 30 damage! zigzagoon is now on " & num3)
                num = num + 1
            ElseIf num = 1 Then
                num2 = num2 - 10
                Console.WriteLine("zigzagoon used tackle! charmander took 10 damage! charmander is now on " & num2)
            ElseIf num = 2 Then
                num2 = num2 - 20
                Console.WriteLine("zigzagoon used quick attack! charmander took 15 damage! charmander is now on" & num2)
            ElseIf num = 3 Then
                num2 = num2 - 25
                Console.WriteLine("zigzagoon used headbutt! charmander took 25 damage! charmander is now on" & num2)
            ElseIf num = 4 Then
                num2 = num2 - 40
                Console.WriteLine("zigzagoon used take down! charmander took 40 damage! charmander is now on " & num2)
                num = num - 4
            End If

            If num1 > 3 And num1 < 5 Then
                num3 = num3 - 40
                Console.WriteLine("charmander used ember! zigzagoon took 30 damage! zigzagoon is now on " & num3)
            ElseIf num = 1 Then
                num2 = num2 - 10
                Console.WriteLine("zigzagoon used tackle! charmander took 10 damage! charmander is now on " & num2)
            ElseIf num = 2 Then
                num2 = num2 - 20
                Console.WriteLine("zigzagoon used quick attack! charmander took 15 damage! charmander is now on" & num2)
            ElseIf num = 3 Then
                num2 = num2 - 25
                Console.WriteLine("zigzagoon used headbutt! charmander took 25 damage! charmander is now on" & num2)
            ElseIf num = 4 Then
                num2 = num2 - 40
                Console.WriteLine("zigzagoon used take down! charmander took 40 damage! charmander is now on " & num2)
                num = num - 4
            End If


        End While

        If num3 <= 0 Then
            Console.WriteLine("the wild zigzagoon fainted! charmander gained 30 xp!. charmander leveled up to level 6!")
        End If


    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: for starters change your variables to something specific. Example: CharmanderCommand, CharmanderHealth, ZigazoonHealth for num1, num2, num3 respectively. that will help you read the code. as for the issue you mention, perhaps instead of a while loop it should be a simple if then statement.

Comment: also use Select Case statements instead of the elseif

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the enemy attacks 3 times is because there are 4 **If/End If** blocks.

When num is set in the first **If/End If** block (*num=num+1*), it gets executed 3 times in the subsequent **If/End If** blocks.

It looks like your *num* **If** statements should be nested inside the first **If** statement. There is a lot of code duplication (which should be converted to functions) that makes it harder to understand.

I took the liberty of rewriting your code:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim charmanderAttack As Integer
    Dim charmanderHealth As Integer
    Dim zigzagonAttack As Integer
    Dim zigzagoonHealth As Integer

    Console.WriteLine("select the wild zigzagoon's health.")
    zigzagoonHealth = Console.ReadLine
    Console.WriteLine("select charmander's health.")
    charmanderHealth = Console.ReadLine
    Console.WriteLine("a wild zigzagoon appeared! go, charmander!")

    zigzagonAttack = 0
    While zigzagoonHealth > 0 And charmanderHealth > 0
        Console.WriteLine("what will charmander do? use tackle(1), burn(2), smack(3) or ember(4)?")
        charmanderAttack = Console.ReadLine
        CharmanderAttacks(charmanderAttack, zigzagoonHealth)

        zigzagonAttack += 1
        ZigzagonAttacks(zigzagonAttack, charmanderHealth)
    End While

    If zigzagoonHealth <= 0 Then
        Console.WriteLine("the wild zigzagoon fainted! charmander gained 30 xp!. charmander leveled up to level 6!")
    End If
End Sub

Sub CharmanderAttacks(ByRef charmanderAttack As Integer, ByRef zigzagoonHealth As Integer)
    Select Case charmanderAttack
        Case 1
            zigzagoonHealth -= 15
            Console.WriteLine("charmander used tackle! zigzagoon took 15 damage! zigzagoon is on " & zigzagoonHealth)
        Case 2
            zigzagoonHealth -= 20
            Console.WriteLine("charmander used burn! zigzagoon took 20 damage! zigzagoon is now on " & zigzagoonHealth)
        Case 3
            zigzagoonHealth -= 30
            Console.WriteLine("charmander used smack! zigzagoon took 30 damage! zigzagoon is now on " & zigzagoonHealth)
        Case 4
            zigzagoonHealth -= 40
            Console.WriteLine("charmander used ember! zigzagoon took 40 damage! zigzagoon is now on " & zigzagoonHealth)
    End Select
End Sub

Sub ZigzagonAttacks(ByRef zigzagonAttack As Integer, ByRef charmanderHealth As Integer)
    Select Case zigzagonAttack
        Case 1
            charmanderHealth -= 10
            Console.WriteLine("zigzagoon used tackle! charmander took 10 damage! charmander is now on " & charmanderHealth)
        Case 2
            charmanderHealth -= 20
            Console.WriteLine("zigzagoon used quick attack! charmander took 20 damage! charmander is now on " & charmanderHealth)
        Case 3
            charmanderHealth -= 25
            Console.WriteLine("zigzagoon used headbutt! charmander took 25 damage! charmander is now on " & charmanderHealth)
        Case 4
            charmanderHealth -= 40
            Console.WriteLine("zigzagoon used take down! charmander took 40 damage! charmander is now on " & charmanderHealth)
            zigzagonAttack -= 4
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: ah, i see! thanks for the explanation! i didn't know it worked like that  - thanks :D

Comment: No problem. It would be great if you can up vote my answer :)